# .net core 6 web api, how to serialize classes derived from Dictionary?

Tags: serialization, asp.net-core-webapi, xml-serialization

I have a class that looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Item", Namespace = "")]
public class Item : Dictionary<string, string>
{

}
```

I have a controller which returns a bunch of items.

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> Query()
{
 ...
}
```

When I call the api an accept json,  the response is exactly what I want:

[
{
"Id": "270",
"PropertyX": "z1",
"AnotherProperty": "270"
},
...
]

When I call the api an accept xml,  I have an exception:

```
An error occurred while trying to create a DataContractSerializer for the type 'Item'.
      System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'Item' cannot be ISerializable and have DataContractAttribute attribute.
```

What I'm really trying to do is serialize an object that can have any set of properties (hence inheriting from Dictionary) and have those properties serialize nicely in the object.  If I don't injerit from Dictionary, and make a property of type dictionary instead,  the dictionary serializes as a child of my Items object which I don't want.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).